# IOS encryption different in Xcode11 above

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Before xcode11, the encryption get for both ios12 below and ios13 above is the same.

But after upgrade to xcode11, the encryption in ios12 below is still the same. But in Ios13 above, the encryption string i get include "length" and "bytes".

IOS12 below

> a7eec1e7b1514058683ebae8e1d86b6b37d4b0e8f6316cbfcd2b42c5ec5952e450c8b0b68e26cbb560fcbc158261c3d7365125b9ec0fb4f7b484beeaf12827ba04c7e8e86b735e04427e0f3957fda8c0ca3133c1d8f4218a415b8740422b41a60bf54e3f8c32d0d3fba4a9de1d59fc4603c97baa6387f1f0b9b27b1e0722350f04b763f002d38afe99553b1511e8c12db3aae59f30a02b44529d3c4866b9449cdb40b60a7b19dbf5e4e47da39c1c3995470c463cf82dfdb1247f7d524076292248f31b43d49c31ec4f76233763190e2c

IOS13 above.

> {length=208,bytes=0xa7eec1e7b1514058683ebae8e1d86b6b...fac0266ed36ff1ef}

What i want is to get only the bytes in IOS13. 
Sorry for my bad english.
and Thanks for the helps

Comment: How did you generate this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, yours is not the more accurate way to ask a question here but let's try to solve it anyways:

I guess that you are obtaining that encryption from some data doing something like:

```
NSString *encryptionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",encryptionData];
```

In the past iOS versions it used to work ok returning only the String, but starting in iOS13 you will get the description of the data, something like:

```
$1 = 0x0000000283373150 @"{length = 32, bytes = 0xf394ff84 a55f406d 165ab4fd d17eca51 ... 5c4cfdd1 06856852 }"
```

Nowadays you need to transform the data, sending the data to method as follows:

```
NSString * encryptionString = [self stringFromData: encryptionData];
```

The method to be called is:

```
- (NSString *) stringFromData:(NSData *)myData {
    NSUInteger length = myData.length;
    if (length == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    const unsigned char *buffer = myData.bytes;
    NSMutableString *hexString  = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(length * 2)];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", buffer[i]];
    }
    return [hexString copy];
}
```

This method will return the NSString that you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. I take over others project to do. He use the wrong method to get the encrypted string. I have fixed it with the same method. (Y)